# How to convert php function to kotlin android?

Tags: php, android, kotlin

I have a project I'm working on that uses an API for it request, but in order to preform them I need to generate the token first.

Before the API was update everything was working, after the update I don't know how to adjust my code to make it work again.

This was the code that worked before the update **(Android | Kotlin)**:

```
fun hmacHash(str: String, secret: String): String {
    val sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")

    val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(secret.toByteArray(), "HmacSHA256")
    sha256HMAC.init(secretKey)

    return convertToHex(sha256HMAC.doFinal(str.toByteArray()))
}

fun convertToHex(data: ByteArray): String {
    val buf = StringBuilder()
    for (b in data) {
        var halfbyte = (b.toInt() shr 4) and (0x0F.toByte()).toInt()
        var two_halfs = 0
        do {
            buf.append(if (halfbyte in 0..9) ('0'.toInt() + halfbyte).toChar() else ('a'.toInt() + (halfbyte - 10)).toChar())
            halfbyte = (b and 0x0F).toInt()
        } while (two_halfs++ < 1)
    }
    return buf.toString()
}
```

Which was equivalent to this **PHP code**:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $privateKey);
```

But now after the update the php code looks like this:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $string, hex2bin($privateKey));
```

And I don't know how to adjust my code to make it work with this new change.

Comment: What kind of value is in the `secret` passed to `hmacHash` in your Kotlin code? Is it plaintext like `"hello123"` or is it hex-encoded like `"3a1b4c1d5e9f"`

Comment: It is a value of the api key passed as the secret in my case it is stored as a plain random string value

Comment: This is an example call in my android code: `hmacHash("${username}::${password}", API_KEY);`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can deduce, the PHP code made that change because `$privateKey` went from being plain text to being hex-encoded. So `hex2bin` was needed to change it back to plain text ([hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) changes hex-encoded text to plain text; a confusingly named function if you ask me).

Since your `secret` is plain text, you don't need to change anything to match. But there are other ways to improve your code. For example, converting a byte array to a hex-encoded string is much easier than that.

```
fun hmacHash(str: String, secret: String): String {
    val sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")

    val bytes = secret.toByteArray()
    val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(bytes, "HmacSHA256")
    sha256HMAC.init(secretKey)

    return convertToHex(sha256HMAC.doFinal(str.toByteArray()))
}

fun convertToHex(data: ByteArray): String =
    data.joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code suggestion it is much nicer than before.

I've spoken with the developer who  created the API and we think that the problem is with androids function `toByteArray` as it returns 64 bytes instead of 32. And that is why the authorization is failing.

Comment: @IgorIlic If the length of your API_KEY is 32 characters and it only contains ASCII characters, then that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: After talking with him again he said that the api key is 64 chars longs as it is encoded and basically you take 2 chars from the string to convert it to single byte in order to get the 32 version. So if a have a string like: `test` I would take `te` convert to byte and take `st` and convert to byte and combine them to get 2 item in a byte array. As explained in the simple terms, but from what I was able to get it is not that simple of a conversion.